# How to disconnect a socket after streaming data?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am making use of "socket.io-client" and "socket.io stream" to make a request and then stream some data. I have the following code that handles this logic

**Client Server Logic**

```
router.get('/writeData', function(req, res) {
    var io = req.app.get('socketio');
    var nameNodeSocket = io.connect(NAMENODE_ADDRESS, { reconnect: true });

    var nameNodeData = {};

    async.waterfall([
        checkForDataNodes,
        readFileFromS3
    ], function(err, result) {
        if (err !== null) {
            res.json(err);
        }else{
            res.json("Finished Writing to DN's");
        }
    });

    function checkForDataNodes(cb) {
        nameNodeSocket.on('nameNodeData', function(data) {
            nameNodeData = data;
            console.log(nameNodeData);
            cb(null, nameNodeData);
        });
        if (nameNodeData.numDataNodes === 0) {
            cb("No datanodes found");
        }
    }

    function readFileFromS3(nameNodeData, cb) {
        for (var i in nameNodeData['blockToDataNodes']) {
            var IP = nameNodeData['blockToDataNodes'][i]['ipValue'];
            var dataNodeSocket = io.connect('http://'+ IP +":5000");
            var ss = require("socket.io-stream");
            var stream = ss.createStream();

            var byteStartRange = nameNodeData['blockToDataNodes'][i]['byteStart'];
            var byteStopRange = nameNodeData['blockToDataNodes'][i]['byteStop'];
            paramsWithRange['Range'] = "bytes=" + byteStartRange.toString() + "-" + byteStopRange.toString();

            //var file = require('fs').createWriteStream('testFile' + i + '.txt');
            var getFileName = nameNodeData['blockToDataNodes'][i]['key'].split('/');
            var fileData = {
                'mainFile': paramsWithRange['Key'].split('/')[1],
                'blockName': getFileName[1]
            };
            ss(dataNodeSocket).emit('sendData', stream, fileData);
            s3.getObject(paramsWithRange).createReadStream().pipe(stream);
            //dataNodeSocket.disconnect();
        }
        cb(null);
    }
});
```

**Server Logic (that gets the data)**

```
var dataNodeIO = require('socket.io')(server);
var ss = require("socket.io-stream");
dataNodeIO.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Succesfully connected!");
    ss(socket).on('sendData', function(stream, data) {
        var IP = data['ipValue'];
        var blockName = data['blockName'];
        var mainFile = data['mainFile'];
        dataNode.makeDir(mainFile);
        dataNode.addToReport(mainFile, blockName);
        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(mainFile + '/' + blockName));
    });
});
```

How can I properly disconnect the connections in `function readFileFromS3`. I have noticed using `dataNodeSocket.disconnect()` at the end does not work as I cannot verify the data was received on the 2nd server. But if I comment it out, I can see the data being streamed to the second server.

My objective is to close the connections in Client Server side

Comment: Well `.disconnect()` is how you close a socket.io connection.  It's not clear why you think that isn't what you want.

Comment: @jfriend00 disconnect() does work, but the way I am using it is leading to an issue where I can't see the see the data being sent over to another server

Comment: Well, you need to explain that other problem then because there's no other way to close the socket.io connection.

Comment: @jfriend00 added an edit to the question

Comment: It does look like maybe you're not even waiting for your socket to connect before trying to use it.  `io.connection()` is not as synchronous call.  It finishes sometime later.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am new to socket.io, i followed this logic based on https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream. Would you say my code will have to alter to disconnect the connections

Comment: Well, there's all sorts of things wrong with your socket.io usage.  For one, you shouldn't be creating a new connection to your host inside your `for` loop.  Create one connection and use it over and over.  Also, you have to wait for the `connection` event before the socket is ready to be used.  And, you will have to iterate differently than a plain `for` loop if you want to run these serially.

Comment: @jfriend00 so the reason its in a for loop is because var IP = nameNodeData['blockToDataNodes'][i]['ipValue'] can be a different value

Comment: It would take a bit of a rewrite to fix.  I can probably help later when I'm on a real screen and keyboard if someone else doesn't do so first.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the main problem with closing the socket is that you weren't waiting for the stream to be done writing before trying to close the socket.  So, because the writing is all asynchronous and finishes sometime later, you were trying to close the socket before the data had been written.

Also because you were putting asynchronous operations inside a `for` loop, you were also running all your operations in parallel which may not be exactly what you want as it makes error handling more difficult and server load more difficult.

Here's the code I would suggest that does the following:

1. Create a function `streamFileFromS3()` that streams a single file and returns a promise that will notify when it's done.
2. Use `await` in a `for` loop with that `streamFileFromS3()` to serialize the operations.  You don't have to serialize them, but then you would have to change your error handling to figure out what to do if one errors while the others are already running and you'd have to be more careful about concurrency issues.
3. Use try/catch to catch any errors from `streamFileFromS3()`.
4. Add error handling on the stream.
5. Change all occurrences of `data['propertyName']` to `data.propertyName`.  The only time you need to use brackets is if the property name contains a character that is not allowed in a Javascript identifier or if the property name is in a variable.  Otherwise, the dot notation is preferred.
6. Add socket.io connection error handling logic for both socket.io connections.
7. Set returned status to 500 when there's an error processing the request

So, here's the code for that:

```
const ss = require("socket.io-stream");

router.get('/writeData', function(req, res) {
    const io = req.app.get('socketio');

    function streamFileFromS3(ip, data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const dataNodeSocket = io.connect(`http://${ip}:5000`);
            dataNodeSocket.on('connect_error', reject);
            dataNodeSocket.on('connect_timeout', () {
                reject(new Error(`timeout connecting to http://${ip}:5000`));
            });
            dataNodeSocket.on('connection', () => {
                // dataNodeSocket connected now
                const stream = ss.createStream().on('error', reject);
                paramsWithRange.Range = `bytes=${data.byteStart}-${data.byteStop}`;

                const filename = data.key.split('/')[1];
                const fileData = {
                    'mainFile': paramsWithRange.Key.split('/')[1],
                    'blockName': filename
                };
                ss(dataNodeSocket).emit('sendData', stream, fileData);
                // get S3 data and pipe it to the socket.io stream
                s3.getObject(paramsWithRange).createReadStream().on('error', reject).pipe(stream);
                stream.on('close', () => {
                    dataNodeSocket.disconnect();
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        });
    }

    function connectError(msg) {
        res.status(500).send(`Error connecting to ${NAMENODE_ADDRESS}`);
    }

    const nameNodeSocket = io.connect(NAMENODE_ADDRESS, { reconnect: true });
    nameNodeSocket.on('connect_error', connectError).on('connect_timeout', connectError);
    nameNodeSocket.on('nameNodeData', async (nameNodeData) => {
        try {
            for (let item of nameNodeData.blockToDataNodes) {
                await streamFileFromS3(item.ipValue, item);
            }
            res.json("Finished Writing to DN's");
        } catch(e) {
            res.status(500).json(e);
        }
    });
});
```

Other notes:

I don't know what `paramsWithRange` is as it is not declared here and when you were doing everything in parallel, it was getting shared among all the connections which is asking for a concurrency issue.  In my serialized implementation, it's probably safe to share it, but the way it is now bothers me as it's a concurrency issue waiting to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the response, paramsWithRange is declared globally, i made modifications to the code as you suggested but I am getting an 
{"type":"TransportError","description":503} error on /writeData. Is there a config value that needs to be set

Comment: @RRP - Where is that error coming from?  I'm not familiar with the `socket.io-stream` library you're using.  I just attempted to copy the way you were using it, but add more event handlers to monitor it.  Try commenting out the `dataNodeSocket.disconnect();`.  Perhaps we're still closing the socket too early.

Comment: That previous suggestion was just meant as a diagnostic test.  Perhaps we need to find a different event that happens a bit later in order to close the socket.

Comment: I added a print statement right before disconnect(), and it didn't print out so i think it fails before that

Comment: So another thing I tried was was changing the "connection" listener to "connect", but this only goes through the item in the loop and then doesn't process the rest