# Read a file from S3 and stream it using socket io

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, socket.io

If I have two servers, "Client Server" and "Server 2". The job of the "Client Server" is to read a file from S3(AWS) and stream it over to "Server2" using socket.io. The "Server2" should store the data on its disk.

**Client Server**

```
var paramsWithRange = {
    Bucket: bucketParams.Bucket,
    Key: bucketParams.Key,
    //Range: "bytes=" + byteStart.toString() + "-" + byteStop.toString()
};

router.get('/writeData', function(req, res) {
    var ss = require("socket.io-stream");
    var io = req.app.get('socketio');
    ........
    ............
  function readFromS3(){
        var ss = require("socket.io-stream");
        var dataNodeSocket = io.connect('http://' + IP + ":5000");
        var stream = ss.createStream();

        var getFileName = nameNodeData['blockToDataNodes'][i]['key'].split('/');
        var fileData = {
            'mainFile': paramsWithRange['Key'].split('/')[1],
            'blockName': getFileName[1]
        };

        ss(dataNodeSocket).emit('sendData', stream, fileData);
        s3.getObject(paramsWithRange).createReadStream().pipe(stream);
  }

}
```

**Server2**

```
var dataNodeIO = require('socket.io')(server);
var ss = require("socket.io-stream");
dataNodeIO.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Succesfully connected!");
    ss(socket).on('sendData', function(stream, data) {
        var IP = data['ipValue'];
        var blockName = data['blockName'];
        var mainFile = data['mainFile'];
        dataNode.makeDir(mainFile);
        dataNode.addToReport(mainFile, blockName);
        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(mainFile + '/' + blockName));
    });

});
```

At the moment, I am able to see the data being stored in "Server2", but its only partial data as I am able to verify this by checking the file size. For instance I am sending over a 100MB text file, I am only able to see 14MB on "Server2".

I followed the `socket.io-stream` documentation on sending data/writing data, but I am not sure why I only get partial file data.

Comment: Related to the question you posted yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49223987/how-to-disconnect-a-socket-after-streaming-data.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes similar code, was trying to target a different problem

Comment: Did you try waiting for the `dataNodeSocket` to be connected before trying to stream to it?

Comment: So when i do dataNodeSocket.on('connect', function(){}) and call the emit and piping in that callback. I seem to be getting an error Error: stream has already been sent.

Comment: Then, you're probably not doing it correctly.  I can't help you debug it without seeing the actual code you tried.

Comment: Its something like this..    
 dataNodeSocket.on('connect', function() {
                ss(dataNodeSocket).emit('sendData', stream, fileData);
      s3.getObject(paramsWithRange).createReadStream().pipe(stream);
  });

Comment: Hmmm, it appears that the `connect` event can fire more than once.  It will fire if your socket.io connection gets dropped and has to reconnect.  I wonder if that's happening for you.  You could `console.log()` it to see with the `blockName` in the console message.  For diagnostic purposes, you could also listen for the `reconnect` message.

Comment: Sorry I didn't follow, so if I need to verify it, I need to console.log() on the server2 side?

Comment: You need to see if the cause of your problem is the `connect` event firing more than once for a given socket (because of a dropped connection that was reconnected).